# Creating a generic data overflow function using bit shifting or math in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, functional-programming, mathematical-optimization

## Use Case

I am learning functional programming. During this exercise, I wanted to create a function that naturally overflows. As an example, if the range of the data is from 2-12, if the value of the input is 12 and you add 1 to it, it becomes 2. Likewise, if you subtract 1 from 2, it becomes 12. It should be noted that I want to improve my math skills because I haven't been thinking like a mathematician for the past 15 years. So forgive me if this looks fairly trivial.

### Implementation

The first implementation was the following:

```
var confineRange(value, min, max) {
  var newValue = value;

  while (newValue > max) {
    newValue -= max;
  }

  while (newValue < min) {
    newValue = max - (min - newValue);
  }

  return newValue;
}
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/b9q8V/)

This implementation worked, but seeing a loop, meant that it could be improved. So the second version I attempted was this:

```
function confineRange(value, min, max) {
  if (value > 0) 
    return (value % max - min)
  if (value < 0) 
    return ((value + max) % max) - min
  if (value == 0)
    return max - min;
}
```

However, this version looks like it could be simplified even more.

### Questions

1. How could this be encapsulate in a single mathematical function?
2. Would it be possible to create this function using bit-shifting? If so, how?
3. Is there a more elegant solution using native javascript functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for simplicity let's see for positive integers only, assuming that the `max` > `min` relation of the parameters are met, and `value` is larger or equal to `min`:

```
function confineRange(value, min, max) {
 return ((value - min) % (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

The bottom end of your range is `min`, and you want to confine within a `max - min + 1` range. For example with your example of `min = 2` and `max = 12` the result can get 11 distinct values! (And not 10 like it may seem first).

Let's test it with the edge cases:

```
confineRange(2, 2, 12);
```

This will execute `((2 - 2) % (12 - 2 + 1)) + 2`, which results 2, good.

```
confineRange(12, 2, 12);
```

This will execute `((12 - 2) % (12 - 2 + 1)) + 2`, which results 12, also good. Note that `12 - 2` makes 10, which is the largest integer which will pass through `% 11` unmodified. Now let's try with 13:

```
confineRange(13, 2, 12);
```

Now after partially calculating it, it will look like `(11 % 11) + 2`, which will make 2 as expected (that is if that 13 was reached as 12 + 1, then it will seem to properly wrap around to 2).

So the basic idea is this.

The function however might fail with numbers below 2 due to how Javascript may or may not handle negative numbers, for example see [this article](http://javascript.about.com/od/problemsolving/a/modulobug.htm). I don't know whether the behaviour is standardized or particular browsers may or may not try to fix it, so better assume this undefined.

The problem now is that you have no possibility of feeding negative numbers in the '%' operator, but given this interface you can only solve the problem with '%' (modulo). So an other method has to be employed.

JavaScript has a `Math.floor()` function which always rounds downwards ([check it here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp)). Using this can eliminate the problem of negatives, so let's construct our own modulo from it:

```
function confineRange(value, min, max) {
 t = value - min;
 d = max - min + 1;
 t = t - (Math.floor(t / d) * d);
 return t + min;
}
```

The modulo happens on the third (`t = t - (Math.floor(t / d) * d);`) line, this calculates `t % d` independent of sign. This solution will work properly for numbers below 2 as well, so you will for example get 12 if you supply 1 as `value` with your example.

For your second question the problem is solvable with bit manipulation, but only if the range (the number of distinct values you want to get) is a power of 2. This case applying a proper AND (`&`) mask on the value will do the job.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thought process. I was having a lot of trouble with the negative values and this solution is absolutely fantastic. It's very complete and well written.